# show addition of two simple functions on a measure is simple

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that two functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are simple functions on a measure $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is simple function if

for $\varphi$, $\exists A_1,\dots ,A_n \in \mathcal{A}$, $\exists  c_1, \dots,c_n$  where $$\varphi (x)= \sum^{n}_{i=1} c_i \mathcal{X_{A_i}}(x) $$

similarly for $\varphi$, $\exists B_1,\dots , B_n \in \mathcal{A}, \exists d_1, \dots ,d_n$

$$\psi(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n d_i \mathcal{X_{B_i}} (x) $$

so adding the two functions

$$\begin{aligned}
\varphi(x)+\psi(x) &=  \sum^{n}_{i=1} c_i \mathcal{X_{A_i}}(x) +\sum_{i=1}^n d_i \mathcal{X_{B_i}} (x) 
\\ &= \dots (\text{steps missing} )
\\ &= \sum^{n}_{i=1} d_i \mathcal{X_{c_i}} (x)
\end{aligned} $$

where $C_1,\dots ,C_n \in \mathcal{A}$

**Not sure what are the sets $C$ and the constants**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the $n$ (number of "steps") can differ for $\varphi$, $\psi$, and $\varphi+\psi$. Let $\varphi = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \chi_{A_i}$ and $\psi = \sum_{j=1}^{m} d_i \chi_{B_j}$. We will consider an extra set $A_{n+1}=X \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ and $B_{m+1} = X \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^m B_j$ as well as constants $c_{n+1}=0$ and $d_{m+1}=0$ so that we can write $\varphi = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} c_i \chi_{A_i}$ and $\psi = \sum_{j=1}^{m+1} d_i \chi_{B_j}$ (basically, we added zero to both functions). The reason we do this is so that the $A_i$ cover the whole space $X$, and likewise the $B_j$ cover the whole space. [Many thanks to GNU Supporter for catching my egregious mistake.]

One way is to let the $C$ sets be all possible intersections of the form  $C_{ij}=A_i \cap B_j$. Note that the $C_{ij}$ cover all of $X$. Then for $x \in A_i \cap B_j$ you have $\varphi(x)+\psi(x)=c_i+d_j$. So the end result is something like $\sum_i \sum_j (c_i+d_j) \chi_{C_{ij}}$.

Comment: It's possible that $$A_{i_0} \cap \left(\cup_{j = 1}^n B_j\right) = \varnothing.$$

Comment: The empty intersections *can't* be thrown out.  For example, $A_1 = [0,1), A_2 = B_1 = [1,2]$ and $B_2 = (2,3]$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thank you, I will revise my answer